# Get-AzRoleAssignment command removes part of trhe resource type

Tags: azure

I am using Get-AzRoleAssignment to get information if my managed service identity has access to storage account

```
Get-AzRoleAssignment -ResourceType "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/" -ResourceName "mystorage" -ResourceGroupName "myresourcegroup" -ObjectId myobjectid -RoleDefinitionName "Contributor"
```

However, I get error

```
/subscriptions/123456-21512521-12521521/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Storage/mystorage' should have even number of parts
```

It looks that the command is removing the trailing "storageaccounts" in the resource type and failing because of it. Any idea how I could get this working? I would not like to use the scope switch.

Comment: how about `"Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"` instead?

Comment: thanks. that was it, too obvious for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution was to remove the trailing slash:

```
Get-AzRoleAssignment -ResourceType "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts" -ResourceName "mystorage" -ResourceGroupName "myresourcegroup" -ObjectId myobjectid -RoleDefinitionName "Contributor"
```